# Show that one column is a linear combination of the other two

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following matrix B. I would like to show that column may be expressed as a linear combination of the other two.

The first step I did was row reduce, but I still do not see one column as a linear combination. Can anyone provide hints? Or is there is a systematic way to solve this kind of problem?

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  −1−3i&−8−10i&0−3i\\
  −7−3i&−4−9i&−3−2i\\
  11-3i& -16-12i&6-5i
\end{array}
\right] $$

In its RREF:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  11−3i&16−12i&6-5i\\
  0&\frac{64}{13}-i\frac{190}{13}&\frac{96}{65}-i\frac{92}{65}\\
  0& 0&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

Comment: The fact that the matrix is rank-deficient already tells you that some column is a linear combination of the others. If you want to know specifics, you need to continue to RREF, as some answers explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reduced matrix is not in RREF yet.  If we really want the coefficients that give the third vector as a linear combination of the first two, we could continue your reduction to find that [the RREF](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row%20reduce%20%7B%7B%E2%88%921%E2%88%923i%2C%20%E2%88%928%E2%88%9210i%2C%200%E2%88%923i%7D%2C%7B%20%E2%88%927%E2%88%923i%20%2C%20%E2%88%924%E2%88%929i%2C%20%E2%88%923%E2%88%922i%7D%2C%7B%2011-3i%2C%20%20-16-12i%2C%206-5i%7D%7D) is
$$
\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & \frac{4001}{7730} - \frac{597}{7730}i\\
0 & 1 & \frac{218}{3865} + \frac{464}{3865}i\\
0&0&0
}.
$$
With that: if $x_1,x_2,x_3$ denote the columns of the original matrix, then we have
$$
x_3 = \left( \frac{4001}{7730} - \frac{597}{7730}i\right)x_1 + 
\left( \frac{218}{3865} + \frac{464}{3865}i \right)x_2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\det B=0$, one of the columns has to be a linear combination of the other two. This works for rows too.

Comment: Right, I get that. I am unsure however as to which column is a linear combination of the other two.

Comment: But the problem was to prove that “one column is a linear combination of the other two” and my argument proves that. However, in this case, since no column is a multiple of another column, it happens that *any* column is a linear combination of the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Say $R_{jk}$ is the entry in tow $j$ and column $k$ of the RREF.

It's clear that there exists $a$ with $R_{23}=aR_{22}$. And this makes it clear that the third column is a linear combination of the first two; third coordinate is no problem, previous sentence does the second coordinate, and now since $R_{11}\ne0$ and the rest of the first column is zero you can subtract off a multiple of the first column to get $0$.

(Or, if $C_j$ is the $j$th column: We have $$C_3-aC_2=\begin{pmatrix}*\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},$$so the form of $C_1$ makes it clear that there exists  $b$ with $$C_3-aC_2-bC_1=0.)$$

Answer (score 0):

Find out constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that

$a_{11}=c_1.a_{12}+c_2.a_{13}$

Now verify that the same constants are working for

$a_{i1}=c_1.a_{i2}+c_2.a_{i3}$, ($i=2,3$)